# Not retrieving value from text area

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.5

How do I retrieve values from text area. Certaily is not from value, I get null. For putting the value I just do it between textarea tag, but then, how do I retrieve it.

Do I have to do it using javascript or jQuery?... Is not as simple as input('inputname')?

There's a lot of references but I don't get it.

I want to show a string value (191 characters - default) at text area, and obviously retrieve it back.

Doesn't work

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="strNota">Comentarios</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="strNota" 
              name="text" value=" {{ $cargo->strComentario }} ">  </textarea>
</div>
```

This works

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="strNota">Comentarios</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="strNota" 
              name="text"> {{ $cargo->strComentario }} </textarea>
</div>
```

At my controller it doesn't work

```
$strComentario = $request->input('strNota');
```

Thanks in advance.

Thanks Barghouthi  , a great help...

Part of my view with the problem.

```
      <!--  Listado de partidas
            Listado de partidas
            Listado de partidas
      -->


      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Descuento</th>
                    <th>Importe</th>
                    <th>Saldo</th>
                    <th>Mensual</th>
                    <th>Cambios</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>



      @if (!empty($cargos))
        @foreach($cargos as $cargo)
          <tr>
            <td> {{ $cargo->productoservicioevento->strConcepto }} </td>
            <td> {{ $cargo->fltCantidad }} </td>
            <td> {{ $cargo->dcmPrecio }} </td>
            <td> {{ $cargo->sItDescuento }} </td>
            <td> {{ $cargo->dcmImporte }} </td>
            <td> {{ $cargo->dcmSaldo }} </td>
            <td> {{ $cargo->productoservicioevento->bolMensual == 1 ? 'Si' : 'No' }}</td>
            <td>

      <!--  Borra partida
            Borra partida
            Borra partida
      -->
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" {{ $create ==  true ? '' : ' disabled ' }}

              onclick="
                var resultdelete = confirm ('¿Estas seguro de que deseas borrar la partida?');
                  if (resultdelete)
                  {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById('delete-partida-form-{{ $cargo->idCargo }}').submit();
                  }
              "


              >-</button>
                <form id="delete-partida-form-{{ $cargo->idCargo }}" action="{{ route('cargos.destroy',[$cargo->idCargo])}}"
                  method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                </form>

               / 

      <!--  Edita partida
            Edita partida
            Edita partida
      -->

              <!--<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Editar</button>-->
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-horario-{{ $cargo->idCargo }}">Editar</button>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="edit-horario-{{ $cargo->idCargo }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" >
                      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">

                          <form method="post" action="{{ route('cargos.update',[$cargo->idCargo]) }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">



                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Cambios en partida</h5> 
                                <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label {{ $nota->bolSaldado == 1 ? ' disabled' : '' }}>Pagado</label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" 
                                      id="bolSaldado" 
                                      name="bolSaldado" 
                                      value="1" 
                                      {{ $nota->bolSaldado == 1 ? ' checked disabled' : ($cargo->bolSaldado == 1 ? ' checked disabled' : '') }}> 


                                 </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1 mb-3">
                                </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                      <label for="dcmAbonar">Abonar</label>
                                      <input type="number" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        min="0.00" 
                                        max="{{ $cargo->dcmSaldo }}" 
                                        step="0.01" 
                                        name="dcmAbonar" 
                                        id="dcmAbonar" 
                                        placeholder="Abonar" 
                                        value=0 
                                        {{ $nota->bolSaldado == 1 ? ' checked disabled' : ($cargo->bolSaldado == 1 ? ' checked disabled' : '') }}>
                                    </div>


                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>


                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <input type="hidden" id="idNota" name="idNota" value= {{ $nota->idNota }} >

                                <div class="form-group">
                                  @if ($productos != null)

                                        <label for="idProducto">Producto o servicio<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                        <select name="idProducto" 
                                          class="form-control" 
                                          disabled>

                                        @foreach($productos as $producto)
                                          <option value="{{$producto->idProductoServicioEvento}}" 
                                            {{ $producto->idProductoServicioEvento == $cargo->idProductoServicioEvento ? 'selected' : '' }} > {{$producto->strConcepto}}</option>

                                        @endforeach
                                        </select>

                                  @endif

                                  <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                      <label for="fltCantidad">Cantidad</label>
                                      <input type="number" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        min="0.00" 
                                        max="100000.00" 
                                        step="0.01" 
                                        id="fltCantidad" 
                                        name="fltCantidad" 
                                        placeholder="Cantidad" 
                                        value= "{{ $cargo->fltCantidad }}" 
                                        required 
                                        disabled>
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Cantidad requerida.
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                                      <label for="dcmPrecio">Precio</label>
                                      <input type="number" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        min="0.00" 
                                        max="100000.00" 
                                        step="0.01" 
                                        id="dcmPrecio" 
                                        name="dcmPrecio" 
                                        placeholder="Precio" 
                                        value="{{ $cargo->dcmPrecio }}" 
                                        required 
                                        disabled    >
                                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Precio requerido.
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                      <label for="sItDescuento">Descuento %</label>
                                      <input type="number" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        min="0" max="99" 
                                        step="1" 
                                        id="sItDescuento" 
                                        name="sItDescuento" 
                                        placeholder="Descuento" 
                                        value="{{ $cargo->sItDescuento }}" 
                                        disabled>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                                      <label for="dcmImporte">Importe</label>
                                      <input type="number" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        min="0.00" 
                                        max="100000.00" 
                                        step="0.01" 
                                        id="dcmImporte" 
                                        name="dcmImporte" 
                                        placeholder="Importe" 
                                        value="{{ $cargo->dcmImporte }}" 
                                        disabled>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                      <label for="dcmSaldo">Saldo</label>
                                      <input type="number" 
                                        class="form-control" 
                                        min="0.00" 
                                        max="100000.00" 
                                        step="0.01" 
                                        name="dcmSaldo" 
                                        id="dcmSaldo" 
                                        placeholder="Saldo" 
                                        value="{{ $cargo->dcmSaldo }}" 
                                        disabled>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                      <label for="bolMensual">Cobro Mensual</label>
                                      <center><input type="checkbox" 
                                        id="bolMensual" 
                                        name="bolMensual" 
                                        value="{{ $cargo->dcmImporte }}" 
                                        disabled></center> 
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <p>
                                      <label for="strNota">Comentarios</label>
                                      <textarea class="form-control" 
                                        rows="3" 
                                        id="strNota" 
                                        name="strNota"> {{ $cargo->strComentario }} </textarea>
                                  </p>

                                </div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach
      @endif
</table>
```

Comment: try reading the input with `name` attribute of your `textarea`. `$request->input('text');`

Comment: "*Certaily is not from value*". Yes it is, but the value attribute isn't how you set it.

Answer (score 2):

Textarea doesn't have **value attribute** [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

so you have to put the value like this

```
<textarea name="strNota"> Value goes here.. </textarea>
```

and in your controller you access it like this

```
$request->input('strNota');
```

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. For HTML, the [*HTML Standard*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-textarea-element) is the normative reference. Example code should be posted here, preferably as a runnable snippet. Also worth noting that textarea elements have a *value* property. ;-)

Comment: I can't open this link! https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-textarea-element

Comment: What error message do you get? Try searching for "HTML Living Standard" and see what you can reach.

Comment: the page is just not loading .. The connection has timed out

Comment: no value attribute here https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-textarea-element

Comment: nor here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: Yes, you're correct about there not being a value attribute, my only issue is with referencing w3schools as it has errors .e.g the *form* property of form controls was implemented well before HTML5, which is a defunct term.

Comment: Actually I've try $request->input('strNota'); with no results, that's why I posted, thanks a lot for all your answers.

Comment: you need the name. if name="text" use $request->input('text')

Comment: An error, thanks actually I had corrected it with no results.

Comment: best thing is to put `return dd($request);` first thing in your controller and see whats happening!

Comment: is the textarea inside a form?

Comment: Yes inside the form

Comment: barghouthi you're right, I checked dd($request) and there the textarea is still named text, I've try  another navigator with the same result, is there some enviroment variables I can reset??? dump or something??

Comment: not sure whats happening there! its surely problem in the view!

Comment: did you solve it, show us the whole view if you didn't solve this!

Answer (score 0):

```
$strComentario = $request->input('strNota');
```

'strNota' is ID of your html element, try to get 'text'

```
$request->input('text');
```

as per Vishal Sharma comment

> try reading the input with name attribute of your textarea.
>   $request->input('text'); – Vishal Sharma 8 hours ago